# Drop Down Filter with CPT as Options for Search Form

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I am trying to figure out how to create a drop down to use as a filter with the search form. I would like the options to be the different post types. I've seen on other sites that -

```
<select name="posttype">
        <option name="product" value="product" style="color: #000;">Legal Documents</option>
        <option name="videos" value="videos">Legal Advice - Videos</option>
<option value="link">Legal Advice - Links</option>
<option value="text">Legal Advice - Articles</option>
         <option value="post_type_c">An Attorney</option>
    </select>
```

What do I have to change or add to the search results page so that then correct post types are shown and filtere?

Comment: Have you searched the site? There're plenty of questions for filtering the search results and extending the search form. Reminder: Please don't add random tags until you can't add more. Each tag has a description or at least an amount of questions that show you what this is about.

Comment: I have tried searching the site and other sources and have not been able to find a solution. Do you know of a solution or reference link??????????

Comment: Please see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-post-types+search, then update your question with your research efforts.

Comment: What do you mean? The code I have thus far is from the research I have done, that's what brought me this close to figuring it out. However it does not seem to work for me at all so that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

use for search this form with custom post type list

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
        <input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="Enter keywords ..." onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/><br />
    <?php $types = get_post_types(); ?>

        <select name="posttype">
    <?php foreach ( $types as $type ) {?>
          <option name="<?php echo $type->singular_label ; ?>"
     value="<?php echo $type->singular_label ; ?>"><?php echo $type->singular_label ; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search Help" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi bhavik, thanks your reply however this does not work, it creates a empty drop down. Also with this code how would I then be able to change the label/text for each post type in the drop down?

Comment: <?php foreach ( $types as $type ) {?>
<option name="<?php echo $type->singular_label ; ?>"
value="<?php echo $type->singular_label ; ?>"> please change your label here </option>
    <?php }?>

Comment: The original suggested code did not work for me but wouldn't the new suggestion make the label the same for all post types?

Comment: wait let me give you example.

Comment: sorry i was wrong please use it  <option name="<?php echo $type; ?>"
     value="<?php echo $type; ?>"><?php echo $type ;?></option>

Comment: This does work with listing the post types, however it does not fully answer my question. The problems are - It shows ALL the post types (even the ones I don't want) and I am unable to individually label each post type option. Also my main problem is the search results are not being filtered by the post type when selected.